# Finding number of days by month between two dates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I have an existing query where every line item has a start date and end date. Some of these cross over months, if that is the case I need it to be broken out into multiple rows by month and year.

For example the query currently returns the below.

| Name | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 2023-12-01 | 2024-01-15 |

I need it to end up looking like this instead.

| Name | Start Date | End Date | Month | Year | # of Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 2023-12-01 | 2024-01-15 | Dec | 2023 | 31 |
| Test1 | 2023-12-01 | 2024-01-15 | Jan | 2024 | 15 |

I have looked online and seen that I could potentially use a CTE but I don't know how to implement it into my current query.

Apologies for any formatting issues with the question.

Comment: Will start and end ever span multiple years? For example, 2022-06-01 to 2024-03-15

Comment: yes it could span multiple years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you're looking for using a recursive common table expression, as you mention, using the following:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Name VARCHAR(20), StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @Table (Name, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES
('Test1', '2023-12-01', '2024-01-15'),
('Test2', '2023-11-15', '2024-01-15');;

;WITH rCTE AS (
SELECT Name, StartDate, EndDate, DATEPART(DAY,StartDate) AS Day, DATENAME(MONTH,StartDate) AS MonthName, DATEPART(MONTH,StartDate) AS Month, DATEPART(YEAR,StartDate) AS Year
  FROM @Table
 UNION ALL
SELECT Name, DATEADD(DAY,1,StartDate), EndDate, DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(DAY,1,StartDate)) AS Day, DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,1,StartDate)) AS MonthName, DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,1,StartDate)) AS Month, DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(DAY,1,StartDate)) AS Year
  FROM rCTE
 WHERE StartDate < EndDate
)

SELECT r.Name, r.MonthName, r.Month, r.Year, t.StartDate, t.EndDate, COUNT(1) AS Days
  FROM rCTE r
    INNER JOIN @Table t
      ON r.Name = t.Name
 GROUP BY r.Name, r.Year, r.Month, r.MonthName, t.StartDate, t.EndDate
 ORDER BY r.Name, r.Year, r.Month;
```

| Name | MonthName | Month | Year | StartDate | EndDate | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | December | 12 | 2023 | 2023-12-01 | 2024-01-15 | 31 |
| Test1 | January | 1 | 2024 | 2023-12-01 | 2024-01-15 | 15 |
| Test2 | November | 11 | 2023 | 2023-11-15 | 2024-01-15 | 16 |
| Test2 | December | 12 | 2023 | 2023-11-15 | 2024-01-15 | 31 |
| Test2 | January | 1 | 2024 | 2023-11-15 | 2024-01-15 | 15 |

However, this may not be the best approach.

If you have a calendar table (or a calendar table function) you can do this much more easily, and engine friendly, with something like:

```
SELECT t.Name, t.StartDate, t.EndDate, c.Month, c.Year, c.MonthName, COUNT(1) AS Days
  FROM @Table t
    INNER JOIN RandomSales.dbo.Calendar(1,1) c
      ON c.Date BETWEEN t.StartDate AND t.EndDate
 GROUP BY t.Name, t.StartDate, t.EndDate, c.Month, c.Year, c.MonthName
 ORDER BY t.Name, c.Year, c.Month;
```

| Name | StartDate | EndDate | Month | Year | MonthName | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 2023-12-01 | 2024-01-15 | 12 | 2023 | December | 31 |
| Test1 | 2023-12-01 | 2024-01-15 | 1 | 2024 | January | 15 |
| Test2 | 2023-11-15 | 2024-01-15 | 11 | 2023 | November | 16 |
| Test2 | 2023-11-15 | 2024-01-15 | 12 | 2023 | December | 31 |
| Test2 | 2023-11-15 | 2024-01-15 | 1 | 2024 | January | 15 |

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many years this spans or how resilient you want this to be years out `cal_bounds` is probably best built dynamically or using an existing calendar from the Snowflake marketplace.

Rationale - Get a calendar lookup table with the boundary dates for calendar years. Then fiddle around with least/greatest to get the number of days difference based on the spans. There's an argument that being more explicit here is better with a CASE/WHEN so it's clear why it all works.

```
WITH 
some_sample_data(name, start_date, end_date) AS ( 
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        ('test1', '2023-12-01'::date, '2024-01-15'::date),
        ('test2', '2023-12-01'::date, '2023-12-17'::date),
        ('test3', '2022-06-01'::date, '2024-01-03'::date),
        ('test4', '2023-11-05'::date, '2023-12-11'::date)
),
cal_bounds(first_day_of_month, last_day_of_month) as (
  select dateadd('month', x, '2020-01-01'::date) as first_day_of_month,
         last_day(first_day_of_month, 'month') as last_day_of_month
  from (
    select row_number() over(order by 0) x 
    from table(generator(rowcount => 1824))
  )
)
select name,
       ssd.start_date,
       ssd.end_date,
       monthname(yb.first_day_of_month) as month_name,
       year(yb.first_day_of_month) as _year,
       datediff(day, greatest(yb.first_day_of_month, ssd.start_date), least(ssd.end_date, yb.last_day_of_month)) + 1 as num_days
  from some_sample_data ssd
  left
  join cal_bounds yb
    on yb.first_day_of_month between ssd.start_date and ssd.end_date
    or yb.last_day_of_month between ssd.start_date and ssd.end_date
 order
    by ssd.name,
       yb.first_day_of_month;
```

| NAME | START_DATE | END_DATE | MONTH_NAME | _YEAR | NUM_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 2023-12-01 | 2024-01-15 | Dec | 2023 | 31 |
| test1 | 2023-12-01 | 2024-01-15 | Jan | 2024 | 15 |
| test2 | 2023-12-01 | 2023-12-17 | Dec | 2023 | 17 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Jun | 2022 | 30 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Jul | 2022 | 31 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Aug | 2022 | 31 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Sep | 2022 | 30 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Oct | 2022 | 31 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Nov | 2022 | 30 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Dec | 2022 | 31 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Jan | 2023 | 31 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Feb | 2023 | 28 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Mar | 2023 | 31 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Apr | 2023 | 30 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | May | 2023 | 31 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Jun | 2023 | 30 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Jul | 2023 | 31 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Aug | 2023 | 31 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Sep | 2023 | 30 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Oct | 2023 | 31 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Nov | 2023 | 30 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Dec | 2023 | 31 |
| test3 | 2022-06-01 | 2024-01-03 | Jan | 2024 | 3 |
| test4 | 2023-11-05 | 2023-12-11 | Nov | 2023 | 26 |
| test4 | 2023-11-05 | 2023-12-11 | Dec | 2023 | 11 |